# How to mount a Windows path volume inside a Docker container

Tags: docker

It's OK when I use `docker run --rm -v C:\Python39:/mnt --entrypoint ls alpine -la /mnt` to mount a Windows path into a container in **a native Windows shell**. But when I mount Windows `//var/run/docker.sock` into a container and try to run previous command inside this container it will throw an error.

```
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid volume specification: 'C:\Python39:/mnt:ro'")
```

a.py

```
import docker
import os

print(os.environ["COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS"])

c = docker.from_env()

output = c.containers.run("alpine", "-la /mnt",
entrypoint="ls", volumes={
    'C:\\Python39': {
        'bind': '/mnt',
        'mode': 'ro',
    }
})
print(output.decode())
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
RUN pip install docker
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
ADD a.py .
CMD ["python", "a.py"]
```

```
docker build . -t test
docker run docker run --rm -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock test
```

Comment: Have you tried  replacing all \\ with / and C: with /c ?

Comment: I guess the difference is due to docker-cli on Windows uses a named pipe `\\.\pipe\docker_engine_linux` not `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @iLuvLogix I tried `C:/` and `/c/`. They are not working too. When you use `/c/` inside a contianer it will mount on rootfs of Linux VM (docker machine) on Windows.